# Cant make the text the display name under my Hyperlink to be searchable nor can I get stream chapters to be searchable in my SharePoint website

Tags: sharepoint-online

I can't make the text (display name) under my Hyperlink to be searchable, nor can I get stream chapters to be searchable in my SharePoint website.

Please advise. I want viewers to be able to click on a sub-link to get directly to the chapter information timecode in my video but I cant get it searchable by text or by chapter.

Answer (score 0):

To make the text under your hyperlink searchable, you need to ensure that your content is available in search results. **Note that if the link is in site navigations, it might not be included in search crawls.**

- Go to Site Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Site column.
- Create a new site column and set the type as “multiple line of text”.
- Add it to your list.
- The content will be crawled and mapped automatically.
- After a few moments, you should be able to search the content you want.

To make stream chapters searchable, you can add chapters to your videos uploaded to Stream on SharePoint.

- Select and open a video.
- Select the Video settings icon from the menu in the upper-right corner of the video.
- Toggle Chapters to on.
- Once chapters are enabled, the Chapters icon will appear in the menu in the upper-right corner of the video.
- Select + New chapter to create a chapter. A new chapter will appear based on the position of your cursor on the Seek bar.
- Add a chapter title in the Title field.
- Select the Check mark to the right of the Timecode field to save your chapter information.

This way, viewers can search a video’s chapters and Table of contents to quickly determine which video content is relevant to them and to easily find and jump to a specific section of the video. Let me know if this helps.